# Is the solution to a specific system of linear equations bounded in the unit hypercube?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $B \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, where $m \leq n$, be such that every entry is in $[0, 1]$ and each row sums to $1$. Let $A = BB' \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$, except replace each number on the diagonal with $1$. For example, if $$B = \begin{pmatrix} 0.4 & 0.6 & 0 \\ 0 & 0.5 & 0.5 \end{pmatrix}$$ then $$BB' = \begin{pmatrix} 0.52 & 0.3 \\ 0.3 & 0.5 \end{pmatrix}, \qquad A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0.3 \\ 0.3 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$ Let $v = [1, \dots, 1]' \in \mathbb{R}^m$. Assuming that $A$ is invertible, then is it true that $A^{-1}v$ (the solution to $Ax = v$) is in $[0, 1] \times \dots \times [0, 1] \in \mathbb{R}^m$? Are there any results or theorems that I should look at that could help clarify my thinking?

I've performed some simulations and haven't been able to find a counterexample, but I also haven't been able to see exactly why this is true. Please do note that

1. The definitions seem so contrived because I've created them for a real-world application in social science, and
2. I'm pretty rusty in linear algebra.

Comment: just trying arbitrary numbers; $\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0.5&0\end{pmatrix}v=\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}$, the matrix is indeed invertible and the system is solved by $v=\begin{pmatrix}2\\-1\end{pmatrix}$, neither of its components are within $[0,1]$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Does \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0..5 & 0 \end{pmatrix} correspond to $B$ or $A$ in the notation that I was using? Because $B$ should have all of its rows sum to 1 and $A$ should have all of its diagonal entries equal 1.

Answer (score 0):

**WORK IN PROGRESS**.

As a starting point, we note that the claim is true for $m=2$. Indeed, in this case $BB^T$ is a symmetric $2\times 2$ matrix and so $A$ is of the form
$$
\begin{array}{cc} 
A=\begin{bmatrix}1 & b \\ b &  1 \end{bmatrix}, & b\in (0, 1).\end{array}$$
The fact that $b\in(0,1)$ follows from Cauchy-Schwarz. Indeed, $b$ is determined by the matrix $B\in\mathbb R^{2\times m}$; precisely,$b=B^{(1)}\cdot B^{(2)}$, where $B^{(j)}$ denotes the $j$-th row. By assumption, the entries of each $B^{(j)}$ are nonnegative and sum to $1$, so in particular $$\lvert B^{(j)}\rvert^2=\sum_k (b^j_k)^2\le (\sum_k b^j_k)^2=1.$$
The fact that $b<1$ immediately follows.

We conclude the $m=2$ case by direct computation:
$$
A^{-1}\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{1+b} \\ \frac{1}{1+b}\end{bmatrix}$$
and indeed $\frac{1}{1+b}\in (0,1).$

**PARTIAL PROGRESS IN THE GENERAL CASE**.

We are working on the general case $m>2$ in comments. So far we reached the following point. The matrix $A$ reads
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & a_{12} & a_{13}& \ldots \\ 
a_{12} & 1 & a_{23} & \ldots \\ 
\ldots & \ldots & \ldots&\ldots \end{bmatrix}$$
where $a_{ij}=B^{(i)}\cdot B^{(j)}$ as before. Considering a solution $x$ to $Ax=v$ we have, by definition of $v=(1,\ldots, 1)^T$,
$$\tag{1}
\begin{cases} 
x_1+a_{12}x_2+\ldots+a_{1m}x_m=1, \\ 
a_{12}x_1+x_2+\ldots+a_{2m}x_m=1, \\ 
\vdots \\ 
a_{1m}x_1+a_{2m}x_2+\ldots+x_m=1.
\end{cases}
$$
The goal is to prove that $x_j\in[0,1]$ for all $j\in\{1, \ldots, m\}$. **It is actually enough to prove that $x_j\ge 0$**, because then the bound $x_j\le 1$ would be immediate from (1), since all $a_{ij}$ are nonnegative.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment! I see now that it works for sure in the $m = 2$ case. What should I be considering when thinking about how to extend to $m > 2$?

Comment: I am not entirely sure this is correct though. Sure, $A$ has that form. But is it right that $b\in (0,1)$? It might be that $b\in(0,2)$. This does not impact the conclusion, because $1/(1+b)\in (0,1)$ in any case. But I think it is important to understand this simple toy model in its entirety before moving on to the general case.

Comment: Yes, b has to be in [0, 1]. Each row of the $m \times n$ matrix $B$ sums to 1, and so must have a magnitude at most 1. Since $b$ is the inner product of both rows, then by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality the inner product of the two rows must be at most 1.

Comment: This gave me a simple idea. Write $$A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & a_{12} & \ldots \\ a_{12} & 1 & \ldots \\ \ldots & \ldots &\ldots\end{bmatrix}.$$ Your matrix $A$ is certainly of this form. Now, suppose that $Ax=v$. We want to prove that $x_j\in [0,1]$. IF we already knew that $x_j\ge0$, then proving that $x_j\le 1$ is immediate from $Ax=v$. Would that be enough?

Comment: Yes, great point! The only thing is we have not shown yet that $x_j \geq 0$ for all $j$ and it is not obvious. One way I am thinking about starting is to note that $BB'$ is positive semi-definite, and by the following link (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3034283/sum-of-symmetric-positive-definite-matrix-and-scalar-of-identity) I think that $A$ is positive semi-definite. Maybe there is some result or combination of results we can use to get that $x_j \geq 0$ following from the fact that $A$ is positive semi-definite?

Comment: No, that has nothing to do with positivity of solutions. There is a thing that guarantees positivity of solutions, though. It is called Perron--Frobenius theorem. I wonder if it can be applied here. I'll check as soon as I have some time